# Running the latest version of SQL Server, how to deal with older DB's

Tags: sql-server

I'm running the latest version of SQL Server (Express) on my system.

But I do get backups from customers running older (express) versions. When changing data in these backups, these backups can't be restored to the older version on the customers system.

Should I install an instance of each version of SQL Server Express on my system, to not need to force the customer to upgrade their version after returning their backup?

Or is there a way to export "All the changes" I've made somehow?

And thus only insert/update these changes at the customers system?

Comment: **Either** you can install additional instances of older versions of SQL Server Express, so that you can do the work in whatever version your customer is using - or you can "ship" the changes made back to the customer as a SQL script (no the database directly - but a script to modify the database at the customer's location with your changes)

Comment: Depends, what are you doing for these customers? Would it be easier to script the processes out instead? Sending backups and then returning them seems a bit "odd" to me. What are you actually doing for the clients(?)?

Comment: Hi, I am not aware of the way to "get" all my changes I've made.
But indeed this was one of the methods I came up with.
So is there a tool or method to get all changes since a "restore" or per  date/time?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, I have multiple instances on my machine with different versions, just because customers have also different versions. Then, I just stopped all versions services, only enabled 2014, and start any version service whenever needed. This would give my machine some air to breath !

And yes, I know it sucks that SQL Server doesn't have the capability to restore backups from newer versions using older ones, but it's capable of doing the opposite. But you have to do your best to give your customers the services that they deserve even if it meant to fill up your machine with SQL Server instances.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for catching that, I still need to practice more english to perfect it ;)